# why div is under the image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i want to put the div above the image, but i don't know why it is always under it event if i set the z-index attribute

my code likes:

```html
<main id="content" role="main">
  <div style="text-align: center">
    <img src="assets/header-img.jpg" style="z-index: -1;">
  </div>

  <div class="container" style="background-color: bisque; height: 1000px; margin-top: -680px"></div>
</main>
```

there are two questions:

1. I want to move up container-div, so i use "margin-top:-680px", 680px is the image height. is there any other optional solution?
2. how can move the container-div above the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use relative positioning to be able to use z-index. Then you can use `top` as well which is a bit more robust than negative margins in my experience.

Default positioning is `static` which does not honour `z-index`.

```html
<main id="content" role="main">
  <div style="text-align: center">
    <img src="assets/header-img.jpg" style="position: relative; z-index: 0;">
  </div>

  <div class="container" style="background-color: bisque; height: 1000px; position: relative; top: -680px; z-index: 1"></div>
</main>
```

Comment: your solution can resolve my questions but it will raise another. the whole page will move up 680px and the page will have 680px blank

Answer (score 0):

Altering the margin-top with a negative value will not push the image up, it will just allow the above element to be closer.

To have the div first... just put it first. I've attached a code snippet to show the working example.

```html
<main id="content" role="main">
  <div class="container" style="background-color: bisque; height: 1000px;"></div>
  <div style="text-align: center">
    <img src="assets/header-img.jpg">
  </div>
</main>
```